# How to bind the terminal command on firefox start?

Tags: command-line, firefox

How to set a terminall command to run every time I start firefox? I perfer terminal way, not gui. Thanks!

Comment: are you trying to run firefox with command ?

Comment: No, I'm trying to run the command `rm -rf ~/.wine-pipelight/*; rm -rf ~/.wine-pipelight/./.*; cp -a ~/viewright_backup/. ~/.wine-pipelight/` every time I start firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a custom wrapper for Firefox, like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
rm -rf ~/.wine-pipelight/*
rm -rf ~/.wine-pipelight/./.*
cp -a ~/viewright_backup/. ~/.wine-pipelight/
firefox $*
```

and save it as a script somewhere, e.g. in `/usr/local/bin/firefox-wrapped`

Next, create a custom starter that runs `/usr/local/bin/firefox-wrapped`. I use `alacarte` to create `.desktop` files.

Comment: And where is the .desktop file located? I'm trying to run the firefox locked to launcher. Will it work?

Comment: Using alacarte should put it in all the right places automatically. If you prefer to write your .desktop files yourself, you can put them in ~/.local/share/applications.

Comment: Does it work with unity or with GNOME only?

Comment: many desktop environments and application launchers honor .desktop files in that directory, it's a default location.

Answer (score 1):

edit the firefox lunch properties
command

```
firefox %u; rm -rf ~/.wine-pipelight/*; rm -rf ~/.wine-pipelight/./.*; cp -a ~/viewright_backup/. ~/.wine-pipelight/
```

you can check the lunch in terminal but if you close the terminal the firefox shuts down too

Comment: Ok, so if i change the .desktop file of firefox and replace the command with this, will it work when I run firefox from launcher?

Comment: So, is it possible to change the .desktop file(using terminal) to have this command? Thank you very much!

Comment: yea & you are trying to make your brother re install the wine so many times :s

Comment: No, the problem is that this wine extenssion(pipelight) works only the first time, only after install. So if you want it to run it again, you must reinstall it, which takes several minutes(to download and so on...) So just by doing this, you don't need to wait that long.

Comment: ah ok sorry about the question